# Enthusiast or Enthusiastic

Tags: grammar

- **I am enthusiastic**
- **I am an enthusiast**

As far as I know **enthusiastic** is an `adjective` and **enthusiast** is a `noun`.

**"I am good"**

**"I am a boy"**

are both correct I think in that sense  **enthusiastic**  and **enthusiast**  are both appropriate in this case.

Is my observation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the case or context you are talking about? Often both are correct, but they have slightly different meanings.

- "I am a travel enthusiast" implies sustained enthusiasm over a long time: you are someone who loves to travel.
- "I am enthusiastic about traveling" can either have that same meaning, or it could just be a time-bound feeling: you are excited to be traveling soon.

Enthusiast refers to one's identity, while enthusiastic refers to one's (potentially temporary) state.

**en·thu·si·ast (noun)**
a person who is highly interested in a particular activity or subject.
"a sports car enthusiast"

**en·thu·si·as·tic (adjective)**
having or showing intense and eager enjoyment, interest, or approval.
"the promoter was enthusiastic about the concert venue"

Answer (score 0):

Certainly grammatically, and partially correct semantically.  *Enthusiastic* and *enthusiast* both come from the Greek *ενθουσιαζω*, to be inspired by a god, and an *enthusiast* was once a term applied to what we'd now call a charismatic religious sect. *Enthusiastic*, i.e., full of enthusiasm, has lost its religious connotation and now means per the *OED*, full of "rapturous intensity of feeling".

An **enthusiast** can refer, as you surmise, to someone who is enthusiastic for, in, or of something in particular or in general, and the *OED* gives the following example from 1856:

> The energy and sincerity of **enthusiasts** is powerful in all ages.

But the more modern usage of *enthusiast* is that of devotee of something, implying a keen interest but without the divinely-inspired fervor. Here's an amusing example from a 1996 issue of [*GASBAG*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YF8JAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA64&dq=%22enthusiast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZjKypmbfRAhUEQiYKHdnJCL04ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=%22enthusiast%22&f=false) (i.e., ***G***ilbert **a**nd **S**ullivan **B**oys **a**nd **G**irls, a journal of the University of Michigan Friends of Gilbert and Sullivan Society)

> I'm addicted to Lord Peter [Wimsey]
>       with his Birtish airs and monocle,
>   And Nero Wolfe, and Father Brown
>       (with morals quite canonical).
>   By far there's good old Ellery [Queen],
>       whose puzzles are confusiest --
>   In fact, I am the model of a mystery **enthusiast**!<sup>*</sup>

Here the singer declares his interest in mystery fiction.

---

*This is a parody of the patter song "I Am the Very Model of a Modern Major-General" from Gilbert and Sullivan's *Pirates of Penazance*. Peter Wimsey, Nero Wolfe, Father Brown, and Ellery Queen are fictional detectives.